# How can I conditionally make type information visible to Jackson deserialization?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I am writing some code that deals with various message `Body` types, which may be extended by plugins. Because some of the infrastructure might not know about specific types, I want to have a catch-all generic fallback class that can hold a deserialized "anything". I tried this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = NAME, visible = true, defaultImpl = UnknownBody)
abstract class Body {
    @NotNull
    String text
}

class UnknownBody extends Body {
    @JsonProperty('@type')
    String _bodyType

    @JsonAnyGetter
    @JsonAnySetter
    Map<String, Object> _properties = new HashMap<>()
}
```

This works, but when I try to deserialize a *known* `Body` subtype, I get an exception saying that the `@type` property is not found on them. So I tried splitting the `@JsonTypeInfo` directive:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = NAME, defaultImpl = UnknownBody)
abstract class Body {
    @NotNull
    String text
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = NAME, visible = true)
class UnknownBody extends Body {
    @JsonProperty('@type')
    String _bodyType

    @JsonAnyGetter
    @JsonAnySetter
    Map<String, Object> _properties = new HashMap<>()
}
```

This results in a `null` value for `_bodyType`; apparently the type info is removed from the deserializer early in the process.

Is there a clean way to explain to Jackson that I want the type discriminator to be set on the `UnknownBody` class without causing it to blow up on other subclasses, and without using `ignoreUnknown`, which could cause silent mishandling in other subtypes?